# Perl: Manipulating while(<>) loop in file reading

Tags: perl

My question is regarding the while loop that reads line from files. The situation is that I want to store values from or the entire next line when the while loop `while(<FILEHANDLE>)` is performing the action on present line `($_)`. So what is the way to address this problem? Is there a specific function or module that does this thing?

Comment: Well I learnt a lot with this assignment...just had another small doubt and didn't want to open another thread for something so simple: I have a an empty array @arr where I am filling the elements from another array through a for loop one-by-one: for ($i=1...scalar@arr2) { push(@arr1,$elements[$i]); } ....it doesn't behave as expected !!! can anyone suggest me what am i doing wrong ?? [didn't find particular solutn by googling :(]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process four lines at a time and each set of lines is separated by `@FCC` then you need to change perl's input file separator.

In your script put

`$/="\@FCC"`

This means that when you do (<>), each record you get in $_ is now four lines of your file.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
local $/="\@FCC";

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    #Each time we iterate, $_ is now all four lines of each record.
}
```

**Edit**
You'll need to backslash the `@`

Comment: okei this is elegant ....this one skipped my mind and looks helpful !!! thank you sir....

Comment: Using `@FCC` inside double quotes when it's not actually an array is going to cause a compilation error.

Comment: Edited - escaped the @

Answer (score 0):

You can read from `<>` anywhere, not just in the head of the loop, e.g.

```
while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    my $another_line = <>;
    chomp $another_line;
    print "$line followed by $another_line\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you duskwuff fr your time...I got wat you said but thats not exactly wat i asked for..let me explain....there are set of four lines L1:@CCF.... L2:---characters--- L3:+ L4:---characters--- , Now i capture L1 like this: if(/^\@CCF/){ $first_line=$_; $second_line=(THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ADDRESS CORRESPONDING SECOND LINE IN ONE GO, LIKE $_+1)}....in grep you address the line after pattern matching line with -A option, something like that !!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is small-ish (perhaps less than 1gb) you could just stuff it into an array and walk it:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @lines;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    push @lines, $_;
}

my $num_lines = @lines; #use of array in scalar context give length of array                                             
# don't do last line (there is no next one)                                                                              

$num_lines -= 1;

foreach (my $i = 0; $i < $num_lines; $i++) {
    my $next_line = $i+1;
    print "line $i plus $next_line:",$lines[$i],$lines[$i+1],"\n";
}
```

Note that the semantics of my solution is a bit different from the answer above. My solution would print out everything except the first line twice; if you wanted everything to be printed once, the above solution might make more sense.

Comment: Thank you Doggerel....No my file is not small-ish....ts bigger than 1.5GB and has over 10mil lines :) .....and I knew of this way !!

Comment: 1.5gb is not that big in modern computer memory. If you have an 8gb+ram machine i doubt you would have a problem. 4gb machines may or may not work.

Comment: Can your use case be reduced to "I need to process a file in chunks of N lines" ? if so the line number magic var $. should help you out.

Comment: No sir...its actually not that simple...infact lemme explain...i have file of million lines, but the entries of this file is a set of 4 lines, i.e. number of entries = # of lines / 4....i am trying deal each of these ENTRIES, but program-atically speaking i deal set of 4 lines....and the starting line of these 4 lines always starts with @FCC....hence when my while(<>) is at first line ($_) , i need to access the following 3 lines ....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read *n* lines at a time from a file you can use [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Tie-File-1.00/lib/Tie/File.pm) and use an array to reference *n* elements at a time, like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my $filename = 'path_to_your_file';
tie my @array, 'Tie::File', $filename or die 'Unable to open file';

my $index = 0;
my $size = @array;

while (1) {
    last if ($index > $size); # Be careful! Try to do a better check than this!
    print @array[$index..$index+3];
    print "----\n";
    $index += 4;
}
```

(This is just an example, try to write better code)

As the documentation says, the file is not loaded into memory all at once, so it will work even for large files.

Comment: I knew it... something like this was there !!!! this looks helpful, lets see..... and thaaaaank you ChatterOne